# NoSuchMethodError when starting runTest

Tags: kotlin, testing, junit, kotlin-coroutines

When I run runTest from `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.4`, I receive a NoSuchMethodError. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my stacktrace:

```
'void kotlin.time.AbstractLongTimeSource.\<init\>(kotlin.time.DurationUnit)'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.time.AbstractLongTimeSource.\<init\>(kotlin.time.DurationUnit)'   at
kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineScheduler$timeSource$1.\<init\>(TestCoroutineScheduler.kt:208)     at
kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineScheduler.\<init\>(TestCoroutineScheduler.kt:208)
```

My code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class) class MainTest { @Test fun test() { runTest {}     } }
```

And my Build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation  ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.6.4")
  testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")    
  implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))    
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.8.0")    
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0")    
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")    
  testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")    
  testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")    
  implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre")

  api("org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1")    
  compileOnly("com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4")
}
```

I tried to change the versions of dependencies.